# How to log scaling applied by \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, scaling, includegraphics

I'm currently working on a large-ish document that contains a lot of screenshots. These range from relatively small dialog boxes or details of the screen to some very large overview pictures. I currently use the option `width=\textwidth` for the larger screenshots to scale them down to fit the page (somewhat). I also need to apply some scaling to the other screenshots - some larger images need to be scaled down, some details need to be scaled up.

Now I would like to use a small set of scaling factors throughout the document. The screenshots are all taken from a single application, and I'd rather not have the font size and UI details change size from image to image. To achieve that, my current plan is to use only two or three fixed scaling factors throughout the document. I can apply these manually in the source code, but I need to determine the actual values first. For that, I was thinking about setting every image to `width=\textwidth`, recording the actual scaling applied and then classifying and adjusting the scaling factors.

As far as I can see, the original size and the requested size of each image file is contained in the log file, but on separate lines and in a syntax that is not very parser-friendly. Is there a better way to log the actual scaling factor that is applied to the image?

Comment: The term `How to log scaling`  can be misunderstood as `logarithmic scaling`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know that "science" is a verb now, but "to logarithmic" is a new one to me...

Comment: `to logarithmic` is of course no verb (as long as I am not errant), but given some usual laziness with titles here, the title can be misunderstood at first

Comment: If you use `\adjustimage` from the `adjustbox` package the previous width of the image is provided as `\width` dimension register which can be used with `\ifdim\width>\somevalue` etc. You could also just store the image in a box and take the box size as indicator (which is what `adjustbox` acutally does).

Comment: and then there are the `min width` and `max width` keys provided by `adjustbox` which only scale if needed. Something like `\adjustimage{min width=0.5\textwidth, max width=\textwidth}{image file name}` will work to ensure that images are neither to small or to large.

Comment: It's not enough some like `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=.75\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image}` for all the images?

Comment: You could have a look at my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450710/dynamic-picture-size) in which I am logging how much I am scaling an image. It needs some work to adjust to your needs but I'd say all you need is in there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto\GPT@setup@scale{\wlog{x-scale: \Gin@scalex, y-scale: \Gin@scaley}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

It will log

```
File: example-image-duck.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
x-scale: 1.8696, y-scale: 1.8696
```

and

```
File: example-image-a.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
x-scale: 1.07413, y-scale: 1.07413
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what's going on inside the graphics/graphicx packages. Is something similar to  Gin@filename available...?